# SSL certificate on IIS 7

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6, asp.net

I am trying to install a SSL certificate on IIS 7. I have download a free trial certificate.

After that, this is the steps what I do:

1. Click the Start menu and select Administrative Tools.
2. Start Internet Services Manager and click the Server Name.
3. In the center section, double click on the Server Certificates button in the Security section.
4. From the Actions menu click Complete Certificate Request.
5. Enter the location for the certificate file.
6. Enter a Friendly name.
7. Click OK.
8. Under Sites select the site to be secured with the SSL certificate.
9. From the Actions menu, click Bindings.This will open the Site Bindings window.
10. In the Site Bindings window, click Add. This opens the Add Site Binding window.
11. Select https from the Type menu. Set the port to 443.
12. Select the SSL Certificate you just installed from the SSL Certificate menu. Click OK.

This is the step where I get the message:

> One or more intermediate certificates in the certificate chain are missing. 
>   To resolve this issue, make sure that all of intermediate certificates are installed. For more information, see
>       http://support.microsoft.com/kb/954755

After this, when I access the web site on its first page, I get this message:

> There is a problem with this website's security certificate.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You did the IIS7 part correctly.  The issue sounds like the free cert doesn't have the full cert chain installed on your machine.  Check with the provider of the cert.  They should have a walkthrough on how to add their intermediate certificate.  Basically it's another certificate that your free one depends on.

Additionally, if you want to manage the certs directly, you can do so by going to MMC (just type MMC from start -> run).  Then add the Certificates snap-in for your local machine.  That gives you more visibility into the certificates.

Comment: The free trial certificates typically have their own "free trial" root certificate that is not trusted by any web server or browser. Check out the following URL for Verisign's: http://www.verisign.com/ssl/buy-ssl-certificates/free-ssl-certificate-trial/test-root-ca/trialcainstall.html